# Rails Submit button not submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've moved from BS3 to Materialize so I am going through and changing my forms - I have 4 forms that are extremely similar, but as I switched the first one over it's no longer submitting. The button doesn't even seem like it's getting clicked, but I tied a generic 'logMe' function to it and sure enough it is.

My routes are the exact same for both, the new form is

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_with(model: @statement, local: true) do |form| %>
    <% if @statement.errors.any? %>
      <% @statement.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          Materialize.toast("<%= message %>", 3000);
        });
      </script>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <!--<label for="icon_prefix">SoW Type:</label>-->
          <%= form.label :statement_type, 'Type:' %>
          <%= form.text_field :statement_type, :id => "disabled", :value => (params[:statement_type]), readonly: true, :disabled => true %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">contacts</i>
        <%= form.label :name, "Name:" %>
        <%= form.text_field :name,  :id => 'required_field1' %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">contacts</i>
        <%= form.label :cost, "Cost:" %>
        <%= form.text_field :cost,  :id => 'required_field2' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i>
        <%= form.label :start_date, "Start Date" %>
        <%= form.text_field :start_date, :class => 'datepicker', "data-provide" => 'datepicker', :id => 'required_field4', :placeholder => "YYYY-MM-DD" %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i>
        <%= form.label :end_date, "End Date" %>
        <%= form.text_field :end_date, :class => 'datepicker', "data-provide" => 'datepicker', :id => 'required_field5', :placeholder => "YYYY-MM-DD" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_contact_calendar</i>
        <%= form.collection_select(:client_id, current_user.clients.order(:name),:id,:name, :class => "browser-default", :prompt => "Choose a client" ) %>   
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <%= form.submit 'Submit', :class =>'btn btn-default', :id => 'register', :onclick => "testMe()"%>    
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('select').material_select();
  validate();
  $('#required_field1, #required_field2').change(validate);
});

function testMe(){
  console.log('hi')
}

function validate(){
  if ($('#required_field1').val().length   >   0   &&
      $('#required_field2').val().length    >   0
      ){
      $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
  }
  else {
      $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
  }
}
var from_$input = $('#required_field4').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
    today: 'Today',
    clear: 'Clear',
    close: 'Ok',
    closeOnSelect: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  }),
  from_picker = from_$input.pickadate('picker')

var to_$input = $('#required_field5').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
    clear: 'Clear',
    close: 'Ok',
    closeOnSelect: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  }),
  to_picker = to_$input.pickadate('picker')


// Check if there’s a “from” or “to” date to start with.
if ( from_picker.get('value') ) {
  to_picker.set('min', from_picker.get('select'))
}
if ( to_picker.get('value') ) {
  from_picker.set('max', to_picker.get('select'))
}

// When something is selected, update the “from” and “to” limits.
from_picker.on('set', function(event) {
  if ( event.select ) {
    to_picker.set('min', from_picker.get('select'))    
  }
  else if ( 'clear' in event ) {
    to_picker.set('min', false)
  }
})
to_picker.on('set', function(event) {
  if ( event.select ) {
    from_picker.set('max', to_picker.get('select'))
  }
  else if ( 'clear' in event ) {
    from_picker.set('max', false)
  }
})

</script>
```

I've tried commenting out all JS, switching it to a regular button, linting it and using Rubocop but I don't see anything off. I went through the HTML to make sure the button was inside the form, and it is.

This isn't the first form I've transitioned, but the first I'm having issues with.

(I assume only the view is relevant since it isn't getting to the controller at this point.)

Just to be safe - The view rendering the form is

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12"><span class="flow-text" style="text-align: center;"><h1>New <%= params[:statement_type] %></h1></span></div>
</div>


<% if params[:statement_type] == 'Proposal' %>
    <%= render 'proposal_form' %>
<% elsif params[:statement_type] == 'Concept' %>
    <%= render 'concept_form' %>
<% elsif params[:statement_type] == 'SoW' %>
    <%= render 'sow_form' %>
<% elsif params[:statement_type] == 'Misc' %>
    <%= render 'misc_form' %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', statements_path %>
```

SoW + Proposal work. SoW doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue ended up not being HTML based, but Rails based in the end.

My static element that is populated by a param was causing the issue.

```
<%= f.text_field :statement_type, :id => "disabled", :value => (params[:statement_type]), readonly: true %>
```

By removing the `id: disabled` it resolved the inability for the Submit button to submit. Unfortunately, it also makes `MaterializeCSS` back to highlighting the field when I select it, but my issue was the Submit button not working.